# Why is Swift NIO example uses HTTP/2 to HTTP/1 protocol conversion?

Tags: swift, http2, swift-nio

What's the purpose the `HTTP2ToHTTP1ServerCodec`. Why is it required to convert the HTTP/2 to HTTP/1 protocol?

```
channel.configureHTTP2Pipeline(mode: .server) { (streamChannel, streamID) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in
    // For every HTTP/2 stream that the client opens, we put in the `HTTP2ToHTTP1ServerCodec` which
    // transforms the HTTP/2 frames to the HTTP/1 messages from the `NIOHTTP1` module.
    streamChannel.pipeline.addHandler(HTTP2ToHTTP1ServerCodec(streamID: streamID)).flatMap { () -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in
        // And lastly, we put in our very basic HTTP server :).
        streamChannel.pipeline.addHandler(HTTPServer())
```

This is a modified [code snippet](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-examples/blob/master/http2-server/Sources/http2-server/main.swift#L134) from the Swift NIO example repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP/2 is HTTP(/1) semantics over multiple streams in a single TCP connection (and a new wire protocol). As an option, SwiftNIO therefore can allow you to use the HTTP(/1) data types to handle HTTP/2. That allows you to fully re-use your server/client implementations that you wrote using SwiftNIO and HTTP/1 for HTTP/2 too which for most people is a benefit.

That translation however is absolutely not required. If you prefer to operate on [HTTP2 frames](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio-http2/docs/current/NIOHTTP2/Structs/HTTP2Frame/FramePayload.html) directly, you don't need to add the `HTTP2ToHTTP1ServerCodec` to your pipeline.

---

*Later edit*: I should also point out that the `HTTP2toHTTP1ServerCodec` is actually quite a simple piece of code that literally just translates the inbound and outbound messages between HTTP/2 frames and HTTP/1 message parts. [Code is here](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-http2/blob/master/Sources/NIOHTTP2/HTTP2ToHTTP1Codec.swift#L126-L198).